# Cheaply repair burnt / melted vinyl floor

Tags: repair, vinyl-flooring

I left a pot on the stove too long, and it melted the aluminum drip pan.  When I removed the hot pan from the stove, the liquified aluminum dripped onto the vinyl floor, melting it in several spots (largest spot pictured):

[image: spot on vinyl floor]

A guy at the hardware store suggested I

1. Cut some replacement pieces of vinyl from under the stove (where it won't be noticed).
2. Using an exacto knife, remove the damaged pieces, clean, and replace using contact cement.

How does this approach sound?  Thoughts on skill level needed, durability, et cetera welcome.

Also - I am in a rental unit, so there's a possibility that they won't let me remove the pieces from under the stove.  If so, is there anywhere online that it would be possible to match my vinyl flooring pattern?

Comment: How big are the holes?

Comment: Photo now added; the largest is about 2x4" +/-.

Comment: Yikes - yeah, those are bigger than "wear and tear"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are minor holes that don't cause loss of function of the floor, I think they are probably "wear and tear" that is a legally mandated part of every rental agreement (in the USA), so you could not worry about it and leave them be...

Per your question, properly glued this is way the professionals patch.  I have noticed that they tend to put a little fillet of glue around the border if the patch, I suppose so you are less likely to catch the edge and rip it back up. I'm not sure what the glue is - sorry.

Cut the patch piece first (in rectangular shape) then lay it over the bad spot and use it as a guide to cut the damaged flooring.  This will help you get a patch that's the exact size for the hole.

Comment: Also, referring to your picture above - Notice the grey lines that make the pattern?  Repair guys will make their cuts in those lines whenever possible, to make them less obvious.